# sense of distance

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm translating a book and I don't understand the meaning of "sense of distance" in this phrase. Anyone care to explain?

> A huge thank you too to Nicola Thomas, collaborator extraordinaire, for her valuable suggestions, **for her Australian sense of distance** (indispensable for road trip success) and for  sharing  my  love  of  craft,  fine  food  and  bucolic  countryside.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage, a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions. Questions that do not show prior research are considered [off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: What does a dictionary tell you about the involved words?

Comment: Hi Helmar,
I googled the phrase, but didn't find anything relevant. You can't find this kind of stuff in dictionaries as evidenced by the answer given by Frangipanes.

Comment: That's why mentioned the single words, knowing about sense, distance and realizing that Australia is large would have put you on the right track. And if it didn't you, incorporating why it didn't help you would certainly motivate people more to try to answer your question.

Comment: Point taken. I'll include my thought process in my next questions. Great community BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is from the "Thank you" section of a travel book or some-such. "... her Australian sense of distance" could mean that she understands how long it takes to get to places that are far away.

For example, in the UK, cities and towns are typically very close to each other, and even travelling from London to Edinburgh is only 9 hours by car. In contrast, Australia (and some parts of the USA, for that matter) is not densely populated, so it can take many hours by car to reach the nearest city.

So it follows that an Australian citizen is arguably better at planning breaks and pit-stops on road trips than a UK citizen, as they are more used to travelling those long distances.

That is my best guess on the meaning of the questioned phrase.

Comment: Amazing! This is exactly what it is. Thank you so much for your answer. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @HadiJafari Glad you like my answer - can you please mark it as such? Thanks!

Comment: I did upvote your answer several times. However, it said my vote wouldn't be displayed because I didn't have sufficient reputation points! I'm new to this site, so... You solved my problem and have my heartfelt gratitude. That ought to compensate for my inability to upvote your answer. Thank you again. :-)

Comment: Came back and upvoted your answer, now that I have enough rep points.